# Simplex and Duplex are types of ______?

Tags: communication, duplex

When describing telecommunication systems, it is often important to note whether it is a simplex, half-duplex, or a full duplex communication.

In trying to explain this variable or attribute, I couldn't find an appropriate word to describe these types of communications.

Is there a common term that engineers use to describe the *'simplexity'* or *'duplexity'* of a communication scheme?

I'm thinking along the lines of **transmission direction** or **transmission type**, but both of these descriptions suffer from being potentially incorrect or too vague.  It seems there isn't yet a practical, nor concise, way of explaining this communication attribute.

Comment: Direction? ...Simplex transmission flows in only one direction. Duplex transmission flows in both directions. Half-duplex transmission flows in both directions, but not at the same time.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you see my dilemma in choosing a term.

Comment: Could say communication format/scheme/protocol? The main issue is that simplex/duplex/half-duplex defines so little of the protocol that I don't think we have a word for just that part of it.

Comment: I was at college many years ago and IIRC half-duplex/duplex was just 'transmission mode'. Direction makes some sense, but  transmission direction seems to make no sense as it is a *transmission* which explicitly has a direction, or the protocol is working at a lower level. I think transmission type was already used as a different attribute e.g. data vs control e.g. acknowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Well, perhaps I should've browsed the web a bit longer.

I've found multiple sources that use the following:

- transmission mode
- data transmission mode
- transmission mode type

Some sources:

http://ccm.net/contents/701-data-transmission-transmission-modes

http://www.studytonight.com/computer-networks/transmission-mode

http://greatinformer.blogspot.com/2012/11/data-transmission-modes-types-of-data.html